# Refinerycms 2.1.0 assets not loading property on Heroku

Tags: heroku, refinerycms

I'm trying to deploy a refinerycms app into Heroku. the deployment process goes smoothly but assets are not loading properly in front-end and back-end (see image attached).

1 - I have compiled my assets.
2 - I set config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
3 - Commited my changes.

and still have the same issue.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding any refinerycms assets you are missing to `config.assets.precompile` in `production.rb` file.
i.e.

> `config.assets.precompile += ['refinery/refinery.css']`